# Update regex to only match capital characters in a single word

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following:

```
$tweet = "RT @forunemagazine Comment here RT @foo Blah";

function _process_retweets($tweet) {
  preg_match('/RT +@[^ :]+:?(.*)/ui', $tweet, $retweets);
  if (count($retweets) > 0) {
    $tag = ' {RT} '; // In reality, output could also be {RT|id}, etc. 
                     // but this is not relevant here
    return preg_replace("/RT/ui", $tag, $tweet);
  }
  else {
    return $tweet;
  }
}

echo _process_retweets($tweet);
```

The expected output here is:

```
{RT} @fortunemagazine Comment here {RT} @foo Blah
```

However, because there is a "rt" in @fortunemagazine, the output is:

```
{RT} @fo {RT} unemagazine Comment here {RT} @foo Blah
```

I thought the regex was covered for mistakes like this. It sould only match exactly RT, which could be at the beginning of the string: "RT @UserName" or in the middle somewhere: "... RT @UserName ..." but always in CAPITALS and never is a valid "RT" followed by any other character than a space and then a "@username", in which "username" can be a-zA-Z_

What am I doing wring in the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return preg_replace("/\bRT\b/", $tag, $tweet);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making it case insensitive by adding i in the regex modifier, remove it to match only the capital RT.

Comment: And this advice still doesn't resolve the issue described as "and never is a valid "RT" followed by any other character than a space"

Comment: @zerkms, but it addresses the main issue, the wrongly used option `i`, while your answer is just a line of code without explaining anything.

Comment: @stema: I assumed OP is experienced enough to be able to compare 2 lines of code and see the difference. And after that to read some manuals

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace("/RT(?=\s)/", $tag, $tweet);
```

http://ideone.com/P7dxm

Comment: The OP requires a space followed by a username after the "RT" and not a whitespace character.

Comment: @stema: OP requires RT followed by a space followed by a username. The latter is a small do-yourself on the base of the given solution